# Do we need to set sqlcommand to null after doing sqlcommand.connection.close();

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

So, I am coding it as below,

sqlcommand.connection.close();
sqlcommand = null;

Now, Visual Studio is giving me a warning as it is an unnecessary assignment at sqlcommand = null.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: If Visual Studio tells this, it will likely be true. You can check this by simply setting a breakpoint and having a look. If you still need help, please be more precise and add your source code.

Comment: Can you please show broader context of the code in question? If assigning to `null` is the last thing you do before `sqlcommand` [goes out of scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#928-local-variables) the assignment is indeed redundant - the object will be [garbage collected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#memory-release) nevertheless.

Comment: I am more curious to know if we explicitly need to set SQL command as null after we perform close() or not

Comment: In C# - no, the moment reference goes out of scope it'll be garbage collected. In C# garbage collector checks if there exist living reference to an object in addition to reference counting.

Comment: Does that Mean I'll have to call Dispose() after close()?

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to care about closing of connections and disposing these objects - best practice should be `using`

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(command, myConnection))
    {
               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I know Using statement can sort this out for me. But I am more curious to know  if we need to set SQL command as null after we perform close().

Comment: Or even `using var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);` without `{...}`